# Powershell can't run mount

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

Trying to mount a NFS share onto a Windows 2012 R2 server and unsure of how to interpret errors being thrown.

Running powershell as admin and entering the commands below...

```sh
PS C:\Windows\system32> whoami
domain\myuser


PS C:\Windows\system32> mount -o nolock mapr006:/mapr z:
New-PSDrive : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'o' is ambiguous. Possible matches include:
-OutVariable -OutBuffer.
At line:1 char:7
+ mount -o nolock mapr006:/mapr z:
+       ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-PSDrive], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand



PS C:\Windows\system32> mount mapr006:/mapr z:

cmdlet New-PSDrive at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Root: mapr006:/mapr
mount : Cannot find a provider with the name 'z:'.
At line:1 char:1
+ mount mapr006:/mapr z:
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (z::String) [New-PSDrive], ProviderNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand



PS C:\Windows\system32> get-alias mount

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Alias           mount -> New-PSDrive



PS C:\Windows\system32> New-PSDrive Z -PsProvider FileSystem -Root \\mapr006\mapr
New-PSDrive : The specified drive root "\\mapr006\mapr" either does not exist, or it is not a folder.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PSDrive Z -PsProvider FileSystem -Root \\mapr006\mapr
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (Z:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveRootError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand



PS C:\Windows\system32> New-PSDrive Z -PsProvider FileSystem -Root \\172.18.4.109\mapr
New-PSDrive : The specified drive root "\\172.18.4.109\mapr" either does not exist, or it is not a folder.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PSDrive Z -PsProvider FileSystem -Root \\172.18.4.109\mapr
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (Z:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveRootError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
```

getting numerous errors. I think that the commands tried above conform to what the process [expects](https://serverfault.com/q/509318/456930), so not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point (normally used to linux). Note that in the last command, it tells me `\\172.18.4.109\mapr` is not a folder, but I am actually able to mount this location when using the "Map Network Drive" in the file explorer GUI.

Can anyone with more Windows experience give any advice on debugging tips or what could be going on and how to fix this?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the issue. Are you running PowerShell as administrator? Have you tried it in the ISE? In the ISE it even popped up available shares once I typed the server name and hit backslash.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Very odd. Yes. Have tried with both Powershell and Powershell ISE (both as admin) and same results. Should also note that I am working on a VDI (not the admin, but have access to them, so not sure if there are security restrictions that could be producing this error).

Comment: If you're running as admin _as a different user_, that user may not have access to the same network resources. The `mount` errors are to be expected, given that `mount` is simply an alias for `New-PSDrive`, so you must use the latter's syntax, not that of the Unix `mount` utility.

Comment: @mklement0 When opeing Powershell ISE as admin and running `whoami`, I appear to still be the same account (I assume this is good enough? I really don't use Windows much). As for the `mount` comment, that's interesting as my actual use case was for following a set of docs for mounting an HDFS implementation to Windows desktop (https://mapr.com/docs/60/AdministratorGuide/MountingNFSonWindowsClient.html).

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter: I expect using the same account to run elevated to be good enough, but I'm no expert. The linked document assumes `cmd.exe`, not PowerShell; with a `mount.exe` utility in the PATH, `cmd.exe` will happily execute it when called as `mount`, but in PowerShell the `mount` alias preempts external programs; a simple way around that is to invoke external programs _with their filename extension_: `mount.exe ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you need is simple you can use:

Assuming that the server will be "mapr006" and the folder to mount "mapr"

```
New-PSDrive -Name "z" -Root "\\mapr006\mapr" -Persist -PSProvider "FileSystem"
```

If you need something more complex, I should explain the following:

mount is a alias

```
PS C:\Users\Juan_Pablo> alias mount

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           mount -> New-PSDrive
```

you can see the cmdlets available with:

```
PS C:\Users\Juan_Pablo> get-command *nfs*

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-NfsUser                                        11.5.0.... VMware.VimAutomation.Storage
Cmdlet          New-NfsUser                                        11.5.0.... VMware.VimAutomation.Storage
Cmdlet          Remove-NfsUser                                     11.5.0.... VMware.VimAutomation.Storage
Cmdlet          Set-NfsUser                                        11.5.0.... VMware.VimAutomation.Storage
Application     nfsadmin.exe                                       10.0.19... C:\WINDOWS\system32\nfsadmin.exe
Application     nfsclnt.exe                                        10.0.19... C:\WINDOWS\system32\nfsclnt.exe
Application     nfsmgmt.msc                                        0.0.0.0    C:\WINDOWS\system32\nfsmgmt.msc
```

New-PSDrive does not have all mount options, but you can use "mount" by typing the path of your full location.
Assuming that the server will be "mapr006" and the folder to mount "mapr"

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\mount.exe mtype=hard -o anon -o nolock -o fileaccess=644 \\mapr006\mapr z:
```